# Powersave on 16.04

Tags: power-management, intel-graphics, intel, battery, tlp

I have Asus tp500lb, it comes with core i5 5200U, nvidia 940m, 8GB ram, 1TB disk and 24GB SSD and so on - system is instaled on SSD.

It has preinstalled windows, actually windows 10. In this environment I can work for almost 6 hours on battery. Under Ubuntu 15.10 I had something about 3hours of usage. Then I did some steps from articles

- [AskUbuntu - Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter)
- [ArchLinux - 3x+ battery life](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134109&p=24)
- [ArchLinux - Laptop](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/laptop)

It means TLP, boot parameters and so on.

Then my power consumption fell down to 6-8W (previously 10-14W) which meant almost 6 hours on battery under Ubuntu 15.10.

Then I updated to 16.04 and everything crashed. I have big consumption again - 3 hours on bat. I tried links above again and hoped the result will be same as on 15.10 but no chance.

So my question is, do you know, how to make it better with same or better results like on 15.10?

Thx, kubrdom

Answer (score 1):

Install TLP power management using

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```

for thinkpad 
use the following

```
 sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
```

want to do in one go then use

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
```